# Emotion recognition lip zone processing

Tags: machine-learning, python, image-processing

I want to detect emotions by comparing the cropped lip zone with different templates and  output an emotion based on the score.
So far I've applied:

1. Normalization
2. Discrete and fast Fourier transform
3. Gaussian blur
4. Lip-zone cropping

> [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]

All of the above done in Python with OpenCV, NumPy, matplotlib...
The next step would be applying some other operation in order to get the lip zone more similar to these:

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

> [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]

**ACTUAL OUTPUT**

> [image] [image]

What other operations should I apply on the images above (ACTUAL OUTPUT) in order to:

- reduce noise
- obtain a contour of the lips
- and after that, apply binarization in order to prepare the picture for comparison.